# @EnsuresNonNullIf annotation gives "conditional postcondition not satisfied"-warning

Tags: java, annotations, checker-framework, type-annotation

I'm using the checker framework and type annotations to check for correct use of `@Nullable` and `@NonNull`.
In a Map-like class<sup>1</sup>, the Java specification states that `get(…)`-methods return `null` when the map does not contain an entry for that key.  Therefore, the methods have the `@Nullable`-annotation.  However, when `contains(…)` returns `true`, I like to guarantee that `get(…)` will not return `null`.

How can I do specify conditional NonNull?

As far as I know, you can achieve this by annotating the `contains(…)`-methods with `@EnsuresNonNullIf`, as follows:

```
@Pure
@EnsuresNonNullIf(expression = {"get(#1)", "getMatchingStoredKey(#1)", "getStrict(#1)", "lookup(#1)"}, result = true)
public boolean containsKeyStrict(final @Nullable Class<? extends TKeyClass> key) {
    return super.containsKey(key);
}

@Pure
public @Nullable TValue getStrict(final @Nullable Class<? extends TKeyClass> key) {
    Return super. gets (key);
}
```

However, this causes a warning:

```
the conditional postcondition about 'this.getStrict(key)' at this return statement is not satisfied
```

How should I solve this "postcondition not satisfied"-warning?

My environment:

- Maven: 3.0.4
- Java: 1.7.0_25 (Oracle)
- Checker framework 1.7.0 (via maven plugin)

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/kaspervandenberg/9132925) demonstrates the problem.

---

1) It extends map's functionallity with to retrieve entries with "similar" keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now, my only solution is to combine the `@EnsuresNonNullIf`-annotation with `SuppersWarnings("nullness")`.  E.g.:

```
@SuppressWarnings("nullness")
@EnsuresNonNullIf(expression = {"get(#1)", "getMatchingStoredKey(#1)", "getStrict(#1)", "lookup(#1)"}, result = true)
public boolean containsKeyStrict(final @Nullable Class<? extends TKeyClass> key) {
    return super.containsKey(key);
}
```

To scope the `@SuppressWarnings` you can delegate the implementation to a method not annotated @EnsuresNonNullIf.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> the Java specification states that get(…)-methods return null when the
>   map does not contain an entry for that key

you're right, but only partially right, [check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29), the javadoc states,

> If this map permits null values, then a return value of null does not
>   necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key;
>   it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null. The
>   containsKey operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.

meaning that, if you're mapping a key to a null value, your method `containsKeyStrict` could return `true` and still, your method `getStrict` would return `null`, not because there's no value for that key but because that value for that key is precisely `null`.

To enforce the kind of behavior you need, you could use a [HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) which doesn't allow null values (or keys), or you could add validations to the `put` methods to prevent the insertion of `null` values into your map, good luck.

Comment: True, Map does allow null-values.  However, the checkerframework considers the value type as `@Nonnull` by default, therefore the framework should infer --if it infers anything here-- that the `@EnsuresNonNullIf`-annotation is correct.
An experiment with a field, a `setToNullNull()`-method, and a `get()`-method produced the same warning (perhaps I should post that experiment as well).
To clarify, my question is how can I tell the checkerframework "trust me, I'm telling the truth"?